# Node.js change Number object value inside prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, prototype

I want to add a new method to Number type, and then use it to change its own value. I write below code:

```
Number.prototype.maxx = function(N) {
  if (N > this.valueOf()) {
    //change this number value to N 
  }
}

var X = 5;
X.maxx(7);
console.log(X); //expect to show 7
```

I try something like below codes to change the value

```
this = N;
```

OR

```
this.valueOf(N);
```

OR

```
this.value = N; //of course number do not have any property named 'value'. but I just try it!
```

but none of them working.

Could you please give me some hint to do this.
Thanks,

Comment: Because it's immutable, i'm not sure it makes sense to extend a primitive (which is not recommended anyways). I would instead use `Math.max(X, N)` or wrap this into your own class that allows overwrite of current value.

Comment: @Danosaure Thanks for the comment. Actually, the function that I mention in the question is just an example to simplify illustration of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Number.prototype.maxx = function(N) {
  if (N > this.valueOf()) {
    return N;
  } else {
    return this.valueOf(); 
  }
}

var X = 5;
X = X.maxx(4);
```

One thing that I would like to highlight over here is when you call X.maxx you cannot change the value of this. Instead, you will have to re-assign the value being returned back from the method to X.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change primitive value of the built-in types, as it's stored in a special property (I believe it might be Symbol). Number is immutable as well.

You can still create a method that will return bigger of the two.